# How to increase the performance of the library on TI Sitara am335x?

Tags: optimization, openssl, cryptography, embedded, embedded-linux

I am using OpenSSL library version 1.0.2 for encryption and decryption of files in my project. The encryption and decryption functions take too much time and the whole application performance gets worse.

I am using TI Sitara am335x processor and it has the cryptographic accelerator in it. That is not giving good performance because of system/application constraint. Even I tried to optimize the OpenSSL library for neon coprocessor (auto vectorization) by using the following flags

```
-O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=hard
```

Even this one is failing to give good performance.

Apart from optimizing my application, how can I deal with it from library side?

Comment: I find `-Os` gives the best performance. The smaller code keeps the caches hotter and enjoys a smaller memory footprint. Also see [Build OpenSSL for Sitara](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Build_OpenSSL_for_Sitara), [AM335x Crypto Performance](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_Crypto_Performance) and [Cryptography Users Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cryptography_Users_Guide) on the TI wiki. The first page tells you to configure with `-DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTODEV_DIGESTS`. The page also includes bench marks and speed tests.

Comment: Thank you. But regarding the hardware accelerator, I have already used it in my aplication. The problem is our application recieves data in the chunk of 2kB. I have to encrypt as soon as I get the data chunk. Hardware accelarator would be effective only if I encrypt the data in the larger block say 100kB. By the way have you used -Os in openssl?

Comment: *... I have to encrypt as soon as I get the data chunk. Hardware accelarator would be effective only if I encrypt the data in the larger block say 100kB"* - in that case, you should probably write your own engine to wrap the hardware.

Comment: @jww What is that wrapping the hardware?

Comment: *"By the way have you used -Os in openssl?"* - yes. I even included instructions for switching to it at [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Modifying_Build_Settings) on the OpenSSL wiki.